# c# NEO4J v3 can't create relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a c# project that I'm working with NEO4J 2.3.2 , after updating to version 3 I start to see that my system always fail creating relationships  . thus is my code

```
  View userView = new View { parent = parent, timestamp = currentTime };
  WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
             .Match("(user123:BaseUser{guid: '" + isAuto + "'})", "(y:YoutubeItem{videoId: '" + itemid + "'})")
             .CreateUnique("user123-[r:VIEW]->y")
             .Set("r = {userView}")
             .WithParam("userView", userView)
             .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

and this is the exception

```
"SyntaxException: Parentheses are required to identify nodes in patterns, i.e. (user123) (line 2, column 15 (offset: 127))\n\"CREATE UNIQUE user123-[r:VIEW]->y\r\"\n               ^"
```

and when i go back to the old version everything is working well, what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher now enforces the requirement that nodes must be surrounded by parentheses.

So, in your query, the `CreateUnique` line needs to look like this:

```
.CreateUnique("(user123)-[r:VIEW]->(y)")
```

*By the way, you should be using [parameters](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#parameters) for injecting the `isAuto` and `itemId` values. You are already doing that with `userView`.*